# How do you build Openssl_1.0.0 version 4

Tags: compilation, openssl, version, elf

I have a binary that I am trying to run that seems to specifically require OPENSSL_1.0.0 version 4:

```
Version needs section '.gnu.version_r' contains 2 entries:
 Addr: 0x00000000080486ac  Offset: 0x0006ac  Link: 6 (.dynstr)
  000000: Version: 1  File: libcrypto.so.1.0.0  Cnt: 1
  0x0010:   Name: OPENSSL_1.0.0  Flags: none  Version: 4
```

I have checked the source code out of openssl git and built 1.0.0-stable, but can't figure out how to specifically build what is needed by the binary.

What release should I checkout from the openssl repo and how do I compile it so that it would be usable by this binary?

Here are other possibly relivant fields from it's elf header:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x804a6e0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          214412 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         37
  Section header string table index: 34


Relocation section '.rel.plt' at offset 0x73c contains 37 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
0805b038  00000d07 R_386_JUMP_SLOT   00000000   MD5@OPENSSL_1.0.0

Dynamic section at offset 0x11f0c contains 25 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.0.0]

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 43 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name     
    13: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND MD5@OPENSSL_1.0.0 (4)

Version symbols section '.gnu.version' contains 43 entries:
 Addr: 0000000008048656  Offset: 0x000656  Link: 5 (.dynsym)
  00c:   2 (GLIBC_2.0)     4 (OPENSSL_1.0.0)   2 (GLIBC_2.0)     0 (*local*)
```

Comment: I believe the SONAME `OPENSSL_1.0.0` is the OpenSSL 1.0.x line. That line includes OpenSSL 1.0.1 and 1.0.2. Checkout `OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable`. Also see [Release Strategy](https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html) on the OpenSSL website.

Answer (score 1):

The version you see there is not the version of the library but the (arbitrary) version of the symbol within the table. As jww already pointed out, that refers to `OPENSSL_1.0.0` which is the symbol version string, and relates to the 1.0.x release branch.

See https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2011/06/gold-readiness-obstacle-2-base-versioning/ for one random reference to symbol versioning that I wrote about before.